# Add jSignature to Bootstrap Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add the jSignature widget to a standard Bootstrap form, but so far nothing is appearing on the form (other form fields show fine).

Here's my form:

```html
<form id="saveEvent" action="index.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="yourName">Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yourName" name="yourName" placeholder="Your Name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="yourSignature">Your Signature</label>
    <div id="signature"></div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I'm including all the files at the bottom of the page in the correct order:

```html
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jSignature.min.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/flashcanvas.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#signature").jSignature()
  })
</script>
```

but the signature canvas doesn't show. Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing if that helps:

[image]

I'm not getting any server errors or console errors so quite stumped at the moment - this is my first go at using jSignature.

Answer (score 2):

Upon further inspection with the dev tools I noticed that the height of the signature div was 0px. I ended up adding this to the script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#signature").jSignature({
    height: 200
  });
  $("#signature").resize();
})
```

and this is at least showing the signature capture now.

Answer (score 1):

Hi now this code is working please check to properly your code is correct

**[Ref this code](http://keith-wood.name/signature.html)**

```js
$('#signature').signature();
```

```css
#signature{
 width:300px;
  height:200px;
  border:solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" href="http://keith-wood.name/css/jquery.signature.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.signature.js"></script>



<form id="saveEvent" action="index.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="yourName">Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yourName" name="yourName" placeholder="Your Name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="yourSignature">Your Signature</label>
    <div id="signature"></div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I noticed that you're using a different signature plugin to jSignature. I'd like to use jSignature for this project for a number of reasons - if I can't get it to work I'll use your suggestions.